# Is there a "fair" synchronization mechanism for iOS

Tags: ios, synchronization

I have an app that tends to do a lot of DB activity in a background thread (downloading large database updates), and quite often this process "starves" the UI thread -- I know that the DB is being released at intervals, but the `@synchronized` mechanism that is used is not "fair" and allows the background thread to immediately reacquire the lock.

Is there another mechanism that is reasonably efficient and well-supported (and not too hard to retrofit) (and "fair") that could be used instead?

Comment: What exactly defines a fair lock? Generally speaking, a mutex works as a queue - whichever thread requests access first gets it. How many threads are running in this scenario as well? If there are only two, then there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Are you doing your own locking around SQLite? As I understand it, you shouldn't need to since it's compiled with multithreading on iOS, but if I'm wrong I'd be happy if someone pointed out some info on it :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - You are wrong.  SQLite only protects itself from destructive concurrency by locking individual operations.  Transaction locking, et al, is up to the user.  And if you attempt an operation on a locked DB you get an error that's difficult to handle.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII -- There are two threads.  The problem is that the UI thread is locked out for minutes sometimes, even though the DB thread "comes up for air" every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your issue. Here I have a simple program (albeit running on mac), based on `@synchronized` and pthreads, which clearly shows that `@synchronized` works as expected, assuming you release your locks:

```
void *backgroundThread(void *data)
{
    while (true)
    {
        @synchronized (globalMutex)
        {
            usleep(USEC_PER_SEC / 3);
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t bgThread = NULL;
    globalMutex = [NSObject new];

    pthread_create(&bgThread, NULL, &backgroundThread, NULL);

    NSTimeInterval lastTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    while (true)
    {
        @synchronized (globalMutex)
        {
            NSTimeInterval elapsed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - lastTime;
            NSLog(@"Main Thread 'came up for air' after %lf seconds", elapsed);

            lastTime += elapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.000015 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.003136 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.000637 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.000610 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.000697 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.000576 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.000571 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.337343 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335533 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335253 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335309 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335367 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335223 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335754 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335271 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335211 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.334555 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335245 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335203 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335262 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335252 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335667 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335278 seconds
TestProj[1494:303] Main Thread 'came up for air' after 0.335309 seconds
```

So unless you aren't properly releasing your locks, `@synchronized` is exactly what you need in this scenario. Please elaborate on what your synchronization code actually looks like, so that we can help you more.

Comment: Yeah, I can't reproduce it either, until I can.  I suspect that it happens in combo with storage getting tight, so all the foreground pages are paged out & don't get a chance to grab the lock.

Answer (score 1):

As I underestand @synchronized is  [a convenient way to create mutex locks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW16). It doesn't have to be "fair".

I would recommend to read about [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html). It has a lot of interesting stuff to put all the work which needs to be done in queues (which should provide better resource sharing).

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about blocking your UI thread, you could create a serial dispatch queue for your database operations. This would enable you to queue up some DB operation from the UI thread, without blocking it (the block of work will just be copied to the heap, stored until its turn to be processed).

For example, from the UI thread, you could:

```
database_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.queue", NULL);

dispatch_async(database_queue, ^{
    // Operations on the DB here
});
// The UI will continue responding immediately after here...
```

The queue will process each block one at a time, providing the synchronisation that you need - you just need to make sure all DB operations are done from that one queue.

If you do need to wait until the work has indeed been done, you can swap out the async call for a sync call in those particular instances:

```
dispatch_sync(database_queue, ^{
    ....
    ....
```

Comment: Given that that distinct operations in the background can run minutes, running them on the UI thread is not a viable option.

Comment: This isn't running them on the UI thread. The queue maintains its own thread which the work is done on - you just pass the work to the queue from the UI thread, which is a fast, non-blocking operation. It will not disrupt your UI.

Comment: But I need to interlock between the DB background work and UI thread accesses to the DB.  That's the reason synchronization is needed.  There's only one background thread, so no conflict between parts of the background processing.

Comment: If that's the case, there's not much you can do, other than finding a way to not block the UI thread (e.g. the dispatch method) and then displaying a UIActivityIndicator until the work is done.. At least that would give some feedback to the user, rather than presenting them with an unresponsive application. Another thing you could try is to get the background thread to yield() after it is finished with the lock, giving the UI thread more of a chance to grab it before the background thread takes it again.

Comment: `@synchronized` hides too much of the mechanism to be very flexible.  Can't tell if one has the last instance of the lock or a stacked one, can't get control on the unlock, etc.